# SQL Managment Studio and multiple Servers

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, remote-server

I'm feeling pretty stupid, so there's my question.
An application I work on uses an MSSQL Server hosted on the Amazon EC2 server the application runs on. I have a local version of that db (same structure, same data, different position) on my local machine.
From my machine I am able to connect to the local db (obviously), and to do whatever I need with it. I seem to be able to connect to the remote db too, but when I try to do any kind of query (even a simple select), even if the only connected server is the remote one, and the query is connected to the remote one, all the results I get are from the local one, and this is driving me crazy.

I just want to login with my user on the remote server and be able to do my updates remotely, but apparently all I can do is query on the local server, even if SMSS seems connected to the remote one.
Anybody has the same issue?

Comment: I would suggest you *aren't* connect to the host you think you are. Review you connection (string) details, and double/triple check they are correct.

Comment: I have never seen this issue. In SSMS, check the status bar at the bottom of the query window. This will show the server, SQL version, login name, spid, and database name you are actually connected to.

Comment: The server explorer (on the left side of SSMS by default) isn't directly connected to the query tabs, i.e.: connecting to a new server doesn't change what any of the existing tabs are looking at. When you open a new server connection you need to select that server (or any node inside it) and open a new tab (e.g.: with Ctrl+N) to perform queries against it.

Comment: Right Click the query window and select Change Connection